# using angular router in custom pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a rails app with dashboard page. So the page will be http://mywebsite.com/dashboard. It has few links available which will load pages via ajax and show it in a div section inside the dashboard page. Its all working fine. So lets assume I want to use angular here and I specify code like below.

```
  var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
    myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){



      $stateProvider
        .state('route1', {
            url: "/route1",
            templateUrl: "route1.html"
        })

    })
```

**My doubt is that:**

So in here if dashboard is the root url then the url generated is `http://mywebsite.com/#route1`

What if my dashboard page is defined like this

`http://mywebsite.com/dashboard` and I want to define route like  `http://mywebsite.com/dashboard/#route1`

> Note: Its not a single page application. But I want the dashboard page
>   to be like a single page one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine and the route will be relative to your URL
`http://mywebsite.com/dashboard`.

If you were using HTML5 mode with Angular UI router if you try and interoperate the full URL. But because you are not using HTML5 mode, Angular UI router routes using #.